# Bootstrap dynamically load div into modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to load the html of hidden divs in the bootstrap modal based on the link or button you press using a variable like a class or something dynamic.

The example Code i have setup but does not work and does not load the content in the modal is

HTML

```
    <ul>
    <li class="span4 device">
        <div class="inner">        
            <div class="details1 hide">
                <label class="details1 control-label2">Device Type</label>
                <span class="details1 field2">Really cool device</span>
            </div>
            <div class="details2 hide">
                <label class="details2 control-label2">Device ID</label>
                <span class="details2 field2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et <b>magnis dis parturient</b> montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="details1" data-toggle="modal" href="#product-details">View details 1</a>
        <a class="details2" data-toggle="modal" href="#product-details">View details 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>

var customModal = $('<div class="custom-modal modal fade bs-modal-sm col-sm-12 col-xs-12 modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="modal-ru"><div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div></div></div></div>');

    var linkclass = $('a[data-toggle="modal"]').attr('class');

    $('a[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){    
        $('body').append(customModal);

        $('.custom-modal .modal-title').html( $(linkclass + '.control-label2').html() );
        $('.custom-modal .modal-body').html( $(linkclass + '.field2').html() );    
        $('.custom-modal .hide').show();
        $('.custom-modal').modal();

        $('.custom-modal').on('hidden', function(){
            console.log("hidden");
            $('.custom-modal').remove();
        });
    });
```

You can view it here http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6454/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.you forget add a dot before class name :

```
$('.custom-modal .modal-title').html( $(linkclass + '.control-label2').html() );
$('.custom-modal .modal-body').html( $(linkclass + '.field2').html() );
```

change to

```
$('.custom-modal .modal-title').html( $('.'+linkclass +'.control-label2').html() );
$('.custom-modal .modal-body').html( $('.'+linkclass +'.field2').html() );
```

2.for access to class of `a` tag that clicked you need use this in click event like this :

```
  var linkclass = $(this).attr('class');
```

you can see result here :[link](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6461/)

Comment: looks good but both links only show the content from details1 and the second link does not show the details2 content in the div.

Comment: @Aaron that's right , i update my answer ... !!!